# Biber not working with Biblatex after the update - Mac OS/MikTex/TexStudio

Tags: biblatex, miktex, biber

I have updated all my Latex software, and basically, nothing is working.

Software versions are:
TeXstudio 4.2.1 (git 4.2.1);
Using Qt Version 6.2.2, compiled with Qt 6.2.2 R;
MiKTeX 22.1;
Mac OS Monterey 12.2.1;

So far I have tried deleting all apps, their related directories and files + clean install. Admin \ user versions of the MikTex made no difference. Updating MikTex on the user or admin-level didn't help either.

```
    Process started: biber "business report"
    
    INFO - This is Biber 2.16
    INFO - Logfile is 'business report.blg'
    INFO - Reading 'business report.bcf'
    ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.8, expected version 3.7.
    This means that your biber (2.16) and biblatex (3.17) versions are incompatible.
    See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.
    INFO - ERRORS: 1
    Process exited with error(s)


        miktex-mf: MiKTeX encountered an internal error. miktex-mf: Data: path="Oenology/Latex/Business report" Sorry, but miktex-mf did not succeed. libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type MiKTeX::Core::MiKTeXException: /Users/mik/work3/MiKTeX/mik
    tex/Libraries/MiKTeX/App/app.cpp:1138: internal error
    Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: /Users/AN/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/data/miktex/log/miktex-makepk.log
    Process exited with error(s)

miktex-mf: MiKTeX encountered an internal error. miktex-mf: Data
: path="Oenology/Latex/Business report" Sorry, but miktex-mf did not succeed. libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type MiKTeX::Core::MiKTeXException: /Users/mik/work3/MiKTeX/mik
tex/Libraries/MiKTeX/App/app.cpp:1138: internal error

Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: /Users/AN/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/data/miktex/log/miktex-makepk.log
Process exited with error(s)
```

Here is the log file entry:

```
2022-02-20 02:39:14,685Z INFO  miktex-makepk - this process (1096) finishes with exit code 1
2022-02-20 02:39:19,263Z INFO  miktex-makepk - this process (1103) started by miktex-pdftex in directory /Users/AN/BSc Viticulture:Oenology/Latex/Business report with command line: miktex-makepk --enable-installer --verbose ecti1000 600 600 magstep(0.0)
2022-02-20 02:39:19,264Z INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font ecti1000 at 600 DPI...
2022-02-20 02:39:19,265Z INFO  makepk - The METFAONT mode is: ljfour
2022-02-20 02:39:19,266Z INFO  makepk - Creating ecti1000.pk...
2022-02-20 02:39:19,266Z INFO  makepk - Running miktex-mf...
2022-02-20 02:39:19,266Z INFO  makepk - running: miktex-mf --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=magstep(0.0); nonstopmode; "input ecti1000"
2022-02-20 02:39:19,310Z INFO  miktex-makepk.core - forking...
2022-02-20 02:39:19,373Z FATAL miktex-makepk - The application file miktex-mf could not be started.
2022-02-20 02:39:19,373Z FATAL miktex-makepk - The application file miktex-mf could not be started.
2022-02-20 02:39:19,373Z FATAL miktex-makepk - Info: 
2022-02-20 02:39:19,373Z FATAL miktex-makepk - Source: 
2022-02-20 02:39:19,373Z FATAL miktex-makepk - Line: 0
2022-02-20 02:39:19,376Z INFO  miktex-makepk - this process (1103) finishes with exit code 1
```

Comment: It appears that for some reason the MikTeX Biber package for Mac OS hasn't been updated. I reported this at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/270. Hopefully this is going to be fixed soon.

Comment: The other errors could be related, even though to my untrained eye they look as though they might have a very different cause. I suspect you'd need to open a bug report at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues for those and provide a way to reproduce the error and as many log files as possible.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was due to a packaging error in the MikTeX Biber package for mac OS. The issue has been reported and resolved (https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/270). A follow-up unrelated to the Biber issue has been posted at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/634759/35864.