# Mmiktex-makepk did not succeed

Tags: miktex

Following the previous problem ([Biber not working with Biblatex after the update - Mac OS/MikTex/TexStudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634517/biber-not-working-with-biblatex-after-the-update-mac-os-miktex-texstudio)), MikTex has been updated and there is no visible conflict between Biblatex and Biber.

Unfortunately, I am still not able to compile anything.

Here is the message I get:

```
    Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Wine Trial".tex
    
    miktex-mf: MiKTeX encountered an internal error. miktex-mf: Data: path="Oenology/Latex/Wine Trial" Sorry, but miktex-mf did not
    succeed. libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type MiKTeX::Core::MiKTeXException: /Users/mik/work3/MiKTeX/miktex/Libraries/MiKTeX/App/app.cpp:1138: internal error
    Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: /Users/AN/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/data/miktex/log/miktex-makepk.log
    Process exited with error(s)
    
    
    Process started: biber "Wine Trial"
    
    INFO - This is Biber 2.17
    INFO - Logfile is 'Wine Trial.blg'
    INFO - Reading 'Wine Trial.bcf'
    INFO - Found 20 citekeys in bib section 0
    INFO - Processing section 0
    INFO - Looking for bibtex file 'EM.bib' for section 0
    INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
    INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'EM.bib'
    INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
    INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
    INFO - Sorting list 'nyt/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'nyt' and locale 'en-US'
    INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
    INFO - Writing 'Wine Trial.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
    INFO - Output to Wine Trial.bbl
    Process exited normally
    
    
    
    Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Wine Trial".tex
    
    miktex-mf: MiKTeX encountered an internal error. miktex-mf: Data: path="Oenology/Latex/Wine Trial" Sorry, but miktex-mf did not
    succeed. libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type MiKTeX::Core::MiKTeXException: /Users/mik/work3/MiKTeX/miktex/Libraries/MiKTeX/App/app.cpp:1138: internal error Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: /Users/AN/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/data/miktex/log/miktex-makepk.log
    Process exited with error(s)
    
    
    Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Wine Trial".tex
    
    miktex-mf: MiKTeX encountered an internal error. miktex-mf: Data: path="Oenology/Latex/Wine Trial" Sorry, but miktex-mf did not
    succeed. libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type MiKTeX::Core::MiKTeXException: /Users/mik/work3/MiKTeX/miktex/Libraries/MiKTeX/App/app.cpp:1138: internal error
    Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: /Users/AN/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/data/miktex/log/miktex-makepk.log
    Process exited with error(s)
```

And here is the log section:

```
2022-02-21 19:47:53,308Z INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font ectt1000 at 600 DPI...
2022-02-21 19:47:53,309Z INFO  makepk - The METFAONT mode is: ljfour
2022-02-21 19:47:53,310Z INFO  makepk - Creating ectt1000.pk...
2022-02-21 19:47:53,310Z INFO  makepk - Running miktex-mf...
2022-02-21 19:47:53,310Z INFO  makepk - running: miktex-mf --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=magstep(0.0); nonstopmode; "input ectt1000"
2022-02-21 19:47:53,351Z INFO  miktex-makepk.core - forking...
2022-02-21 19:47:53,435Z FATAL miktex-makepk - The application file miktex-mf could not be started.
2022-02-21 19:47:53,435Z FATAL miktex-makepk - The application file miktex-mf could not be started.
2022-02-21 19:47:53,435Z FATAL miktex-makepk - Info: 
2022-02-21 19:47:53,435Z FATAL miktex-makepk - Source: 
2022-02-21 19:47:53,435Z FATAL miktex-makepk - Line: 0
2022-02-21 19:47:53,437Z INFO  miktex-makepk - this process (1015) finishes with exit code 1
2022-02-21 19:47:55,943Z INFO  miktex-makepk - this process (1018) started by miktex-pdftex in directory /Users/AN/BSc Viticulture:Oenology/Latex/Wine Trial with command line: miktex-makepk --verbose ectt1000 600 600 magstep(0.0)
2022-02-21 19:47:55,944Z INFO  makepk - Trying to make PK font ectt1000 at 600 DPI...
2022-02-21 19:47:55,945Z INFO  makepk - The METFAONT mode is: ljfour
2022-02-21 19:47:55,945Z INFO  makepk - Creating ectt1000.pk...
2022-02-21 19:47:55,945Z INFO  makepk - Running miktex-mf...
2022-02-21 19:47:55,945Z INFO  makepk - running: miktex-mf --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; \mag:=magstep(0.0); nonstopmode; "input ectt1000"
2022-02-21 19:47:55,982Z INFO  miktex-makepk.core - forking...
2022-02-21 19:47:56,048Z FATAL miktex-makepk - The application file miktex-mf could not be started.
2022-02-21 19:47:56,048Z FATAL miktex-makepk - The application file miktex-mf could not be started.
2022-02-21 19:47:56,048Z FATAL miktex-makepk - Info: 
2022-02-21 19:47:56,048Z FATAL miktex-makepk - Source: 
2022-02-21 19:47:56,048Z FATAL miktex-makepk - Line: 0
2022-02-21 19:47:56,052Z INFO  miktex-makepk - this process (1018) finishes with exit code 1
```

Comment: you are missing the map entries for the cm-super fonts. Ensure that cm-super is installed and then remake the font map files (miktex console, user mode, menu tasks).

Comment: Everything works, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the map entries for the cm-super fonts.

Ensure that cm-super is installed and then remake the font map files in the miktex console (user mode) in the Tasks menu.